# Making MacVim/gVim “block” the terminal until closed

Tags: command-line, vim, git, gvim, macvim

A long time ago, before I switched to vims, I used an editor for OS X known as TextMate. (Anyone remember that? ;)

Its command-line binary, `mate`, allowed for a `mate -w` flag, which would block the command-line binary exiting until the file was saved, and closed. This allowed for using `mate -w` as the editor for `git` commit-messages and similar.

Trying to do similar with MacVim (or gVim) doesn't work out; as the `mvim` helper closes as soon as MacVim is launched (or as soon as the file is opened). This results in a “your message was empty,” or similar other error, from whichever program invoked the `$EDITOR`: as far as the program knows, the ‘editor’ (the `mvim` helper-binary) has exited, but the file it's provided to edit is still empty.

Is there some command, configuration setting, or hack that I could use to ensure the command-line `mvim` helper (or whatever alternative alias or script you come up with for me) doesn't exit *until the opened files have been saved and closed in MacVim*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want the `-f` command line option (meaning “stay in foreground”; see `:help -f`). You can usually incorporate it directly into your EDITOR value (or that of VISUAL, GIT_EDITOR, or Git’s `core.editor`, etc.):

```
EDITOR='mvim -f'; export EDITOR
```

This option is not specific to `mvim`; it should also work with `gvim` (i.e. any GUI vim).

Answer (score 2):

Did you know you can run MacVim *in* your terminal emulator?

```
$ mvim -v filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force mvim to block the terminal adding: `-f` or `--nofork`

> -f  or  --nofork  Foreground: Don't fork when starting GUI

So just add this to your profile:

```
export EDITOR="mvim -f"
```